# spring boot mongo db collection get document before a know document id

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, rest

I have developed a Rest api using spring boot with mongo db. So far I am able to add documents and retrieve them using the api.

But I need to implement a path in which the client can provide a document id and I need to retrieve the 10 records that were entered before the provided document id.

I am not able to write the query for this request.

I tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable= collection.find(lt("_id", new ObjectId("5f986445bf87483ade34a3fe"))).sort(descending("_id")).limit(10);
```

`5f986445bf87483ade34a3fe` is the `id` of a known document in the collection.

Comment: transform the `ObjectId` that you have into a `Date` using its `getTimestamp()` method and then create a query on `_id` using that date